# Prevent image in flex container from stretching in Edge

Tags: html, css, flexbox, microsoft-edge

I have an image in flex that stretches in Edge browser but is normal in other browsers. Here is my code and jsfiddle. Open jsfiddle url in chrome and edge.. I want it to look like chrome in edge.

```css
.logo {
  height: 100px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}
.logo img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x70">
</div>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x70">
```

### [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mftnbk38/11/)

Comment: How do you want it to behave?

Comment: open same url in chrome and edge.. i want it to look like chrome in edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `align-self: center` use `align-items: center`.

```
.logo {
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    /* align-self: center; */
    align-items: center; /* new */
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
}
```

The `align-self` property applies to flex items. Except your `div.logo` element is not a flex item because its parent – `body`, in this case – does not have `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex` applied. Therefore, `body` is not a flex container, the `div` is not a flex item, and `align-self` is having no effect.

The `align-items` property is similar to `align-self`, except it applies to flex containers.

However, `.logo img` has `margin: auto` set. This is supposed to be enough to vertically and horizontally center the image in the container. With `margin: auto` on the child, any `align-items` or `justify-content` rules on the container should be overridden.

*From the spec:*

> [**8.1. Aligning with auto margins**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins)
>
> Prior to alignment via `justify-content` and `align-self`, any positive free space is distributed to auto margins in that dimension.
>
> Note: If free space is distributed to auto margins, the alignment properties will have no effect in that dimension because the margins will have stolen all the free space left over after flexing.

Most browsers adhere to the standard behavior. Edge (and IE10 & 11) are not in compliance.